# DataGridView doesn't display Cell Controls when used in UserConrol

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

My goal is to create interactive `DataGridView`, which allows user to set desired parameters using controls such as CheckBoxes, ComboBoxes or NumericUpDowns. Therefore I created new `Windows.Form` with a DataGridView and populated it with aformentioned controls.

```
Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        InteractiveDataGridViewTemplate.AppendDatagridView(DataGridView1)
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class InteractiveDataGridViewTemplate    
    Public Shared Sub AppendDatagridView(dgw As DataGridView)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Name")
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            dt.Rows.Add("")
        Next
        dgw.DataSource = dt
        dgw.Columns(0).Width = 200
        For Each row In dgw.Rows
            CreateCheckBoxCell(row)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub CreateCheckBoxCell(row As DataGridViewRow)
        Dim chBoxCell As New DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
        row.Cells(0) = chBoxCell
        row.Cells(0).Value = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Everything worked as expected. The problem occured when instead of Windows.Form I applied the very same procedure on `UserControl`. In this case all DataGridViewCells turned into TextBoxCells displaying the value intended as starting value for controls (as visualized bellow).

```
Public Class DgwUserControl
    Inherits UserControl
    Private Sub UserControl_Load(s As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
        InteractiveDataGridViewTemplate.AppendDatagridView(DataGridView1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Comparison of the outputs]

Is there any explanation for this strange behaviour? And are there are any ways of resolving this issue? Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The designer is probably interfering with it.  Try mocking a Shown event in the UserControl to overcome that:

```
Public Class UserControl1

  Private wasShown As Boolean = False

  Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'InteractiveDataGridViewTemplate.AppendDatagridView(DataGridView1)
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    If Not wasShown Then
      wasShown = True
      InteractiveDataGridViewTemplate.AppendDatagridView(DataGridView1)
    End If

    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it worked for me. But I still don't quite understand, why it did though. From what you have written I suppose, that the designer somehow altered some of DataGridView properties after LoadEvent had been fired? So since the OnPaint event is fired later then Load event the postponement of Grid population is sufficient to resolve this problem?

Comment: @PepaZdepa That's pretty much it.  The form's load event isn't being run from the designer, but a UserControl's load event is.  Why it interferes with the display, I'm not sure.